# how to convert timestamps in a nullable column to dates in aws athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to convert datatype of string (eg : '2018-03-27T00:20:00.855556Z' ) into date (eg : '2018-03-27')

problem is cast(substring(dt, 1, 10) as date) doesn't work here (INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to date) and the column has null values and empty strings so from_iso8601_timestamp will fail (INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "")

Answer (score 1):

> problem is cast(substring(dt, 1, 10) as date) doesn't work here

Was not able to reproduce, works just fine for me -

```sql
select cast(substring('2018-03-27T00:20:00.855556Z', 1, 10) as date);
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2018-03-27 |

The problem seems to be the same as for `from_iso8601_timestamp` - empty strings, so  you can use [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#id4) (swallows all exceptions and returns null):

```sql
select try(from_iso8601_timestamp(dt)) dt
from (values ('2018-03-27T00:20:00.855556Z'),(null), ('')) as t(dt);
```

or check if string is empty:

```sql
select from_iso8601_timestamp(if(dt = '', null, dt)) dt
from (values ('2018-03-27T00:20:00.855556Z'),(null), ('')) as t(dt);
```

Output:

| dt |
| --- |
| 2018-03-27 00:20:00.855 UTC |
| NULL |
| NULL |